# ASP.NET Profile Provider: is it a value-add?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-profiles

I've been trying to write an open-source profile provider to work against PostgreSQL (I was frustrated with the limitations and incompleteness in the other projects I'd seen available), but the documentation and examples of how people use it was surprisingly sparse.  Even the SO tag for `asp.net-profiles` has a little over 100 questions associated.

The more I dig in to making it work, the less and less practical it seems; the value added does not seem to justify the complications associated; additionally, it only seems to work on a limited scope of web projects without a bunch of extra work.

I feel like I'm being led to the conclusion that it is not a popular technology, and that there are better ways to persist a more robust user-based information set.

Is my take on this fundamentally flawed?  Is this widely used?  I'm on the cusp of abandoning my profile provider as it seems to offer little of value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Profile system in asp.net is not widely used, primarily because of the reasons you mention.  It's just not useful for a lot of people.

The easiest solution is to simply create a profile table in your app, then key it on the ProviderUserkey of the Membership system.

Comment: I was hoping someone would tell me I was overlooking the usefulness of this provider... looks like my gut reaction was the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

I have always eschewed the ASP .NET Membership provider in favor of a custom implementation of `IPrincipal` for one simple reason.  I've almost never needed the out-of-the-box functionality it provides.

Any custom implementation means creating your own implementation of `MembershipProvider`.  Amongst other methods that I have never implemented, it includes wonders like `RequiresQuestionAndAnswer` and `MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts`.  It forces an implementation upon you that you might not need and will take you more time to complete properly.

Sure, you could cheat and put a `NotImplementedException` in methods that you're not particularly bothered about, but what right-minded coder would feel comfortable with that in a production system? :D

I really like a lot of Microsoft's stuff, but my experience is that a lot of their "out-of-the-box" solutions are fine in vanilla mode, but the wheels tend to come off when you travel off the beaten path.  A bit of cherry-picking is therefore required.  My advice?  Leave this one on the vine.

Comment: Hah, I already built the `MembershipProvider` and `RoleProvider` according to the published standards... a lot of uselessness but I understood it as a prerequisite for the `ProfileProvider`... but now it seems that it may not have been necessary.

Comment: I tried it once on a deadline product and was tearing my hair out by day three.

Comment: @PaulAlanTaylor - While I can appreciate that you don't feel it's useful, i've found the default membership provider quite userful in about 50% of my projects.  I've written custom Membeship providers for another 40% and 10% i've went the custom IPrincipal route.  I see nothing wrong with not implementing portions you don't need.

Comment: @MystereMan - I think we'd have to agree to differ on that part.  I have a conceptual problem with signing up to a contract (in this case, implementing the behavior of an abstract class) and not meeting the terms of that contract.